# MYSQL update, subquery, where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have little problem with a SQL statement in Axon Ivy.

```
UPDATE intra_gesuch
SET status = in.gesuch.status, 
    fk_sachbearbeiterin = (SELECT id_sachbearbeiterin 
                           FROM intra_sachbearbeiterin 
                           WHERE in.gesuch.sachbearbeiter.kuerzel = kuerzel);
WHERE casenumber = in.gesuch.casenumber;
```

but I get en error:

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
'WHERE casenumber = 'b4133a49fd94'
    SET status = 'Überprüfung Anforderungen', fk' at line 2
    Failed to execute database query.
  Original Query: UPDATE intra_gesuch WHERE casenumber = in.gesuch.casenumber SET status = in.gesuch.status, fk_sachbearbeiterin =  (SELECT id_sachbearbeiterin     FROM intra_sachbearbeiterin     WHERE in.gesuch.sachbearbeiter.kuerzel = kuerzel)
  Expanded Query: UPDATE intra_gesuch
WHERE casenumber = 'b4133a49fd94'
SET status = 'Überprüfung Anforderungen', fk_sachbearbeiterin =
    (SELECT id_sachbearbeiterin 
    FROM intra_sachbearbeiterin 
    WHERE 'thsc' = kuerzel)
```

Could anyone help me with that problem? Thank you.

Comment: ever tried to remove the `;` after the inner query?

Comment: add distinct to inner query

Comment: what is that `WHERE in.gesuch.sachbearbeiter.kuerzel`  ? show us all tables structure, and sample of data in each one if possible

Comment: is MySQL or MS SQL server?

Comment: SQL queries have syntax.

Comment: This query did not generate this error message